# Take photos using volume buttons

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

Is it possible to take photos using the volume controls on the iPhone?

Ideally, the `takePicture()` method would be called when the volume button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener.

```
Titanium.Media.addEventListener('volume', function(e) {
    Ti.Media.takePicture();    
});
```

Make sure the event listener is added when the camera is already shown. Docs here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-takePicture